# How get the Html-Ajax post array value like below stucture in Django view.py?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have this form:

```
<form id="form">
<input type="text" name="group_name">

<div id="dynamic_form">
    <input type="text" name="members[0][name]">
    <input type="text" name="members[0][date]">

    <input type="text" name="members[1][name]">
    <input type="text" name="members[1][date]">

    <input type="text" name="members[2][name]">
    <input type="text" name="members[2][date]">
</div>
```

I would like to get the Html-Ajax post array value like below stucture in dijango view.py?

Expected Output:

```
{
  "group_name": "SomeGroup",
  "members": [
    {
      "name": "Alice",
      "date": "01/01/2015"
    },
    {
      "name": "Bob",
      "date": "02/01/2015"
    },
    {
      "name": "Carol",
      "date": "03/01/2015"
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: So you want to get such JSON blob when you POST to the view?

Comment: Yes I want form array based group the data